# Absolute Value Condition in Generalized Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> What is the coefficient of $\frac{y^3}{x^8}$ in $(x+y)^{-5}$?  when $|\frac{y}{x}|<1$ *(EAMCET 2020)*

I am using the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$(x+y)^r=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{r \choose k} x^{r-k}y^k$$

Substituting $n=-5$ and $r=3$ in the above gives:
$${5+3-1 \choose 3}(-1)^3=-{7 \choose 3}=-35$$

I did not use the condition $|\frac{y}{x}|<1$ anywhere. Was it required as an assumption for what I did? What would removing that condition do?

Note:

1. I do not know Laurent expansions (though I do know Taylor series), but neither are included in the syllabus of this exam. So answers that refer to the binomial theorem, and how to use it would be appreciated.
2. I am looking at the question from a generating function point of view. So convergence issues are not primary (unless they relate to generating functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When $|\frac{y}{x}|<1$, the Laurent expansion of $(x+y)^{-5}$ is obtained by taking the Taylor expansion of $(1+\theta)^{-5}$, substituting $\theta=\frac{y}{x}$, and multiplying by $x^{-5}$.

When $|\frac{x}{y}|<1$, the Laurent expansion of $(x+y)^{-5}$ is obtained by taking the Taylor expansion of $(1+\beta)^{-5}$, substituting $\beta=\frac{x}{y}$, and multiplying by $y^{-5}$.

The former series does not converge when $|\frac{x}{y}|<1$, and vice versa.

Basically, yes it does matter, the coefficients are NOT the same in the other case.

Comment: The question asks only for the coefficient. Only for the coefficient, is what I did sufficient? Also, I do not know what a Laurent series is. (I do know what a Taylor series is, and I have not done Calculus with Complex numbers).

Comment: @Starlight ah for that, please go to the Wiki page that you had linked, and notice that in the discussion of Newton's version of the theorem (which is the relevant one since the exponent is negative), it says clearly $|x|>|y|$

Comment: I understood the condition now. It is to gaurantee convergence. Considering that I am primarily interested in the coefficients of the series does the convergence matter? You specifically said that the coefficients of the series are not the same.......